# Trying to understand Service error caused by Quotas limitation.

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two similar scripts run on two different spreadsheet every day at midnight, triggered on time Events. I don't know why but since a few days my script aren't executed anymore and I got the following error in my mailbox : `Service using too much computer time for one day`

So I took a look a [Google Apps Quotas guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) but I don't really understand it. I don't understand what part of my script is reaching some limitation and what should I do so solve this issue.

Here is my script :

```
function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data1 = sheet.getRange('data!B3').getValue();
  var data2 = sheet.getRange('data!C3').getValue();
  var data3 = sheet.getRange('data!D3').getValue();
  var data4 = sheet.getRange('data!E3').getValue();
  var data5 = sheet.getRange('data!F3').getValue();
  var data6 = sheet.getRange('data!A3').getValue();
  sheet.appendRow([data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6]);
}
```

Any hint ? Is this because I'm using too much of the same method ? Which Quotas refers to this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is however your code can reduce the number of getRange calls, this will be a little cleaner and slightly faster.  I am assuming sheet[0] is called data:

```
function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getRange('A3:F3').getValues()[0];
  sheet.appendRow([data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[0]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Apps Quotas guide : "Service using too much computer time for one day : This indicates that the script exceeded the total allowable execution time for one day. It most commonly occurs for scripts that run on a trigger, which have a lower daily limit than scripts executed manually."

**Triggers cannot run for longer than 30 seconds.**

Your script might exceed this execution time.

Comment: Not sure where you got that from. A function called by a trigger can run for 6 minutes. All triggers combined you can have a total runtime of 90 minutes on a gmail.com account. @SimonBreton maybe you have more triggers? Remember that **all** triggers setup by your account combined cannot run longer than 90 minutes per day. And do take note of utphx answer, batch your data reads, there is absolutely no need to use `getRange()` that many times in your function

Comment: Thanks @Vytautas I just cleaned all my trigger and refactor my script following utphx advise. What I didn't know is that I'm using a Google Sheet Add-ons which is adding some triggers on my account for refreshing data. I'll tomorrow but make that everything is ok now and suggest a sum up answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all comments and answers I solve my issue. I clean my triggers list accessible from the script editor (ressources => triggers list). I discovered some triggers I didn't know about which where added by a Google Drive add-ons I'm using. I also refactor my code the way utphx advise me.